# React Routger v6 - Check wether child element is active / <Outlet/> would return a Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Good day,
Would you be able to help me regarding my problem with react-router v6's nested element, specifically, the child element?

Let's say I have this routing

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="customer" element={<CustomerIndex />} >
         <Route path=":customeId" element={<CustomerDetail />} />
         <Route path="create" element={<CustomerForm />} />
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

And the "CustomerIndex" component

```
function CustomerPage(){
    const {customerId} = useParams();
    return (
            <>
               //.....Bla bla bla index table etc etc etc end of thinking capacity        
               <ComponentToDisplayModal display={Boolean(customerId)} >
                    <Outlet />
               </ComponentToDisplayModal>
            </>
         );
}
```

Now if I go to "/customer/3", the CustomerIndex would display the Modal Component (display=true) and the  because the "customerId" constant is defined by the useParams

But if I would like to show "CustomerForm" component by navigating to "/customer/create", of course, the 'ComponentToDisplayModal" wouldn't be displayed because customerId is null.

So, of course, I would like to have this instead

```
const display = Boolean(customerId) || isAnyChildPath;
.....
<ComponentToDisplayModal {...{display}}>
```

Now, how could i set "isAnyChildPath" constant to "TRUE" if path is "/customer/*", and "FALSE" if path is "/customer", or maybe, check wether  would return a componen (eg. "/customer/create", "/customer/4"), or not ("/customer") ?

For now, I just use the manual method of

```
const location = useLocation();
const display = Boolean(customerId) || location.pathname === "/customer/create"
```

But I would like to learn if there is exist a more elegant method, in case I need to add several other static childs in the future.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could simplify the child route check a bit by using the `useMatch` hook and check if the current path matches either child route instead of testing by any route path params.

[useMatch](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usematch)

> ```
> declare function useMatch<ParamKey extends string = string>(
>   pattern: PathPattern | string
> ): PathMatch<ParamKey> | null;
> ```
>
> Returns match data about a route at the given path relative to the
> current location.

The idea is that when the route matches a defined match object is returned, otherwise `null` is returned for non-matches.

`"/customer/:path"` can match both `"/customer/:id"` and `"/customer/create"`.

Example:

```
function CustomerPage(){
  const isMatch = useMatch("/customer/:path");

  return (
    <>
      //.....Bla bla bla index table etc etc etc end of thinking capacity        
      <ComponentToDisplayModal display={Boolean(isMatch)} >
        <Outlet />
      </ComponentToDisplayModal>
    </>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-routger-v6-check-wether-child-element-is-active-outlet-would-return]